# mysql creating trigger error code 1064 SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-error-1064

my schema is middleweight(mname, mwins, mlosses, mdraws, mweight, mcountry, mage, mheight)
I am completely lost cant seem to find the problem.

```
delimiter//
CREATE TRIGGER tr_middlewegiht_u
BEFORE update on middleweight
for each row
begin
          IF (new.mweight>185) THEN
             SIGNAL sqlstate '45000'
                  set message_text = 'The fighters in the wrong weight class.';
               END if;
END//
delimiter;
```

Comment: Unrelated but: you should have only a single table with an attribute "weightclass". Do not create one table for weight class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should maintain a `space` between `'delimiter'` key word and its values `'//'`, and `';'`
Unless which it is a `1064 syntax error`.

**Example**:

```
delimiter // -- <--- observe the space here. It is a MUST

-- your trigger definition

end;

//

delimiter ; -- <--- maintain space here too. This too is a MUST
```